# Android : Pager Title Strip and WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar

I created a project with "Swipe View+Title Strip" navigation type for Android 4.0. What I want is to show a different page when I click on a title or I swipe between pages. For example I have three tabs, each one of these to show a different webpage. I now how to create a simple webview app, which loads a webpage with javascript and so on. PLEASE CAN SOMEONE HELP ME TO MODIFY THIS CODE SO THAT EVERYTIME I CLICK A TAB FROM THOSE TITLES TO SHOW SOMETHING DIFFERENT.
I saw something with int position and then switch(position){ case 0, case 1, case 2} etc. but I don't know where to put this code.

This is the stock code, can someone modify it for me? I am searching about this for weeks :((.

```
package com.actionbartest;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
etc.

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
 * sections. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will
 * keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best
 * to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}




/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
 * sections of the app.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create for example 3 html files in your assets/www folder (index1.html, index2.html, index3.html) than change onCreateView() *on the end* from generating text view to generate webview, like:

```
    WebView mWeb = new WebView(getActivity());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWeb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWeb.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
mWeb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index"+args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)+".html");
return mWeb;
```

Bad thing in this approach is that when you swipe webview reloads. You should set onCreateView to populate view only once and prevent webview from reloading on swipe, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

**I hope somebody who read this will leave comment on how to prevent webviews from reloading every time it's section comes in focus.**